# How to view name a part of a JSON Object?

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring

I am testing out a new way to use Springboot and having trouble with a JSON Object that holds a few filenames. I am having trouble reading the filenames from the object, as I do not really know what they are called.

Controller:

```java
@RestController
@Slf4j
@RequestMapping("/application")
public class ApplicationController {

    @GetMapping
    public List<String> fileSelection() {

        List<String> files = new ArrayList<>();

        URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("placeholder.txt");
        File dir = null;

        try {

            dir = new File(url.toURI()).getParentFile();

        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        for (File f : dir.listFiles(path -> path.getName().contains(".txt"))) {

            if (!f.getName().equals("placeholder.txt")) {

                files.add(f.getName());

            }

        }

        return files;

    }

}
```

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<select id="test"></select>

</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```js
function getLines() {

    fetch(`/application`, {

        method: 'GET'

    }).then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {

            console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
            let html = ""
            data.forEach(d => html += `<option>${d.value}</option>`)
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = html

        })

}
```

The Problem lies at the data.forEach(d => html += `<option>${d.value}</option>`) line, where I am just not sure what to put in there in order to print the filenames into the selection.

Comment: If you post an example of the object? Start with `.then(data => console.log(data))` to find out

Comment: This is the output in the console, I hope it is enough.

Array(2)
0 : "data.txt"
1 :  "data2.txt"
length : 2

Comment: `.then(data => document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = data.map(filename => \`<option value="${filename}">${filename}</option>\`).join(''));`

Comment: Huh, it worked. Thank you, but I don't think I understand everything in the comment above. Mind explaining it to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comment you say `data` is an array.
Since you already trust the data enough to use innerHTML, we can do the following

```
.then(data => document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = data
  .map(filename => `<option value="${filename}">${filename}</option>`).join('')
);
```

since

```
data.map(arrayItem => console.log(arrayItem))
```

will show

```
"data.txt"
"data2.txt"
```

and I just wrap that in `<option value="arrayItem">arrayItem</option>` using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in a NEW array I then immediately join with nothing to make

`<option value="data.txt">data.txt</option><option value="data2.txt">data2.txt</option>`

before inserting it into the select

Comment: Wish I could upvote you, since I am missing the reputation for it, but I definitely would have. Thank you a lot.